# How can I create a Perl script to get some "named" command line arguments?

Tags: perl, command-line

How can I create a Perl script to get some "named" command line arguments?

For example:

```
perl my_perl.pl -ARG_1 1234 -ARG_2 "Testing"
```

Where ARG_1 and ARG_2 are the arguments names and 1234 and "Testing" their values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get a similar effect by using [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html).  The main difference is that it uses gnu-style --arguments by default.  It's very flexible and powerful.

Answer (score 7):

See [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). If you do not like that, there are many [others](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=getopt&mode=module).

In the simplest case, you could do:

```
my %args = @ARGV;
print $args{-ARG_1}, "\n";
```

Comment: for really simply use, there's also perl's -s switch: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-s%2A

Comment: I may be wrong, but -s seems to work for one liners only.